# Get Android Pixel Values

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen, android-screen-support, android-gesture

I have searched alot of this issue on google but unable to get any help.My question is **how to get pixel position of android screen where the user has tapped?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this does the job.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
```

Comment: Thanks, my onTouchEvent() not get called whenever I run my application. Are there any Listeners thats need to be setup?

Comment: don't think so, see [this](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/handle-ontouchevent-in-surfaceview.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for: [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`getRawX`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawX%28%29) and [`getRawY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawY%28%29)?

Comment: What is the difference between getRawX or Y and getEventX and Y?

Comment: `getRawX()` gives x-coordinate of event on screen, and `getX()` gives x-coordinate of event on view. So, `getX()` may be negative, if you move finger to left of your view.